# PHP Email Form Help - @ symbol not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

Emails won't be sent if the @ symbol is in the form submitted in the email line.  Ie: if you type bob in the email form, it works, but bob@gmail.com doesn't.  how can i fix it to work properly?  the email won't send at all if the @ symbol is in the line.

```
<?php
$to = "MYEMAIL@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$subject= "Request For Quote from Latva";
$message = "
Full Name - $name
Email - $email
Address - $add
City - $city
State - $state
Zip - $zip
Phone - $phone
Message - $comments
";
  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
         $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
         $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";
         foreach($_FILES as $userfile)
         {
            $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
            $type = $userfile['type'];
            $name = $userfile['name'];
            $size = $userfile['size'];
            if (file_exists($tmp_name))
            {
               if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
               {
                  $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
                  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
                  fclose($file);
                  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
               }
               $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
               $data . "\n\n";
            }
         }
         $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
   echo "Mail sent successfully.";
else
   echo "Error in mail";
?>
```

Comment: You have to take care that you correctly escape all strings you put into the headers. Those can only access 7bit characters. So you need to convert everything else by encoding. Similar is true for "special characters" like line break chars and stuff. Just imagine what happens if you enter such stuff into the `$name` variable...

Comment: **Stop manually building email headers**. Your headers are vulnerable to injection that would allow attackers to send spam from your server. There are lots of pitfalls. Use a proper class like http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: What @arkascha meant to say is: use a mail library